# HBase storing files

Tags: hadoop, hbase, store

I want to save a file in Hbase.

How can I do this?

I prefer to use a solution without using hdfs , the files are small sized, so I think they can be stored directly in HBase .

Comment: Your question is very vague and is likely to get closed. You must come with something more specific and also show what you have tried. I recommend you take the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You can base64 encode file content, and store in any database... HBase can be ran in Standalone mode, without HDFS, if that's the question